# Display the rendered feed in a view which is in NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, nsdata

The below is the code I used to get a data of URL from a facebook page. I need to display those datas in a view. How to do it?

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/104958162837/posts/10151442797857838"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                           NSData * data,
                                           NSError * error) {
                           if (!error){

                               NSLog(@"%@",data);

                               // I want to render this data in a view.

                           }

                       }];
```

I can get the proper values in the in NSData. I want to display those datas in a webview or uilabel or something to display those datas.

Comment: What data did you get? Json? XML? or HTML?

Comment: @OhSeungKwon Am getting Json as response from facebook API and I Parse   the Json to get a link and I want to render this link in a view.

Comment: See my answer. I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `NSData` into `NSString` and then use that `NSString` for display.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxx"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                           NSData * data,
                                           NSError * error) {
                           if (!error){

                               NSLog(@"%@",data);

                               // I want to render this data in a view.
                               NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                               //[lbl setText:myString];

                                /** EDIT : As you are getting HTML Response, you can display that in WebView like this **/

                               [webview loadHTMLString:myString baseURL:nil];



                           }

                       }];
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your reply I will give a try and get back to you.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/104958162837/posts/10151442797857838 I want to dislay this response in some view. I tried what you have said and am getting HTML format.

Answer (score 2):

See this code.

```
id dataObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

You can get json string to NSObject(like NSDictionary, NSArray)

Comment: Thnaks I will give a try and let you know.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/104958162837/posts/10151442797857838 I need to display this response in a view. What you have said is to get a response from Json. Can you please check the link and give some idea. I need to display what ever is ther in the link.

Comment: I don't have privilege for this page. Check this out